# Is there a way to write to a dataframe based on data in another data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 data frames (df_text and df_excel) and I am trying to load the write a script that takes the latest date (in this example it would be 2023-02-12) from the 'end' column in df_text, match it to the dates column in (df_excel) then write the 'status' from df_text to df_excel for the correponsing name column.

### df_text

```
    Name    start                 end              status
0   N1  2023-02-08 02:01:45 2023-02-08 08:15:01 completed
1   N2  2023-02-09 06:04:25 2023-02-09 10:35:50 completed
2   N1  2023-02-09 06:04:25 2023-02-09 10:35:50 completed
3   N1  2023-02-10 13:46:01 2023-02-10 16:35:50 completed
4   N4  2023-02-10 16:35:25 2023-02-10 19:35:50 started
5   N1  2023-02-11 16:35:25 2023-02-11 19:35:50 completed
6   N3  2023-02-11 16:35:25 2023-02-11 19:35:50 completed
7   N2  2023-02-11 16:35:25 2023-02-11 19:35:50 started
8   N4  2023-02-12 18:54:03 2023-02-12 23:53:09 completed
```

### df_excel

```
Unnamed: 0 2023-02-08 00:00:00 2023-02-09 00:00:00  ... 2023-02-12 00:00:00 2023-02-13 00:00:00 2023-02-14 00:00:00
0         N1           Completed           Completed  ...             Waiting             Waiting             Waiting
1         N2             Waiting           Completed  ...             Waiting             Waiting             Waiting
2         N3             Waiting             Waiting  ...             Waiting             Waiting             Waiting
3         N4             Waiting             Waiting  ...             Waiting             Waiting             Waiting
4         N5             Waiting             Waiting  ...             Waiting             Waiting             Waiting
```

SO since the latest 'end' date in df_excel is 2023-02-12, and the corresponding name is N2 and the status is 'completed', then the cell for N4 in column '2023-02-12' in df_excel should be changed from 'waiting to 'completed'.

Is there a way to programatically do this?

So far I have this script that reads the txt and excel file but not sure the best approach for next> maybe match the dates from the 'end' column in the df_txt with the column in the df_excel and then write the status from the df_txt to the df_excel for the correponsing name (N1,N2,N3 etc).

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import time
df_text = pd.read_csv('data/text.txt', sep='|',
                      skiprows=(0, 2,)).iloc[:, 1:].applymap(str.strip)
# df_text
df_excel = pd.read_excel('data/excel.xlsx', skiprows=1)
print(df_excel)
```

Comment: Do you have some formatting in `df_excel` you want to keep?

Comment: @Corralien I guessing keeping the format as it is would be nice the column 0 is for the values N1/2/3/4, then each column after is the date (example '2023-02-08 00:00:00') with the values waiting/completed/started underneath

Comment: What is the output of `print(df_excel.columns)` please? And how do you read the excel file for `df_excel`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
# Read excel file correctly:
df_excel = pd.read_excel('source.xlsx', index_col=[0])  # to have N1, N2 as index.

# Retrieve the last row
row = df_new.iloc[-1]

# Use indexing to modify value
df_excel.loc[row['Name'], str(pd.to_datetime(row['end']).normalize())] = row['status'].capitalize()
```

Output:

```
>>> df_excel

   2023-02-08 00:00:00 2023-02-09 00:00:00 2023-02-12 00:00:00 2023-02-13 00:00:00 2023-02-14 00:00:00
N1           Completed           Completed             Waiting             Waiting             Waiting
N2             Waiting           Completed             Waiting             Waiting             Waiting
N3             Waiting             Waiting             Waiting             Waiting             Waiting
N4             Waiting             Waiting           Completed             Waiting             Waiting
N5             Waiting             Waiting             Waiting             Waiting             Waiting
```